# Can't connect to github

Tags: ssh, github, ubuntu-11.04

I have been following This Tutorial.

However When it comes to doing `ssh git@github.com` I am getting

> PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

If I do 
`ssh git@github.com -v` I get

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hailwood/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hailwood/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve hailwood
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve hailwood
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([207.97.227.239]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_NZ.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github doesn't offer shell access, so trying to `ssh` to github will fail (as you see, the authentication succeeds, but you don't get a pseudoterminal). Try to `git clone` some public repo instead and see if it works.

Comment: That is not right. When one tries to `ssh git@github.com -v`, the expected answer would end with "`Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access`". The OP was not getting that answer, so it seems he had indeed an issue with his SSH configuration.

Comment: @rsenna: Except for that message, the log output is similar to what I get, including the last PTY rejection, so I suppose that the OP's SSH client just didn't show the final message from the server (or that he forgot to paste it). Since the OP accepted the answer, I presume that he succeeded in cloning the repository; hence his SSH setup probably was correct.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Anyway, guess my comment is important to anyone else with similar problems, so I'll keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Git offers shell access but after you go another step further. Follow this tutorial they offer: http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Comment: Actually for SSH I would recommend https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles